# How to resolve horizontal drag conflicts between Drawer and bottom view in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, drawer

In Flutter, the width of the area where the Drawer is dragged horizontally can be set by setting the **DrawerEdgeDragWidth**; But when a horizontal drag operation is set in my main view, there will be a **conflict** between the two, and the horizontal drag operation in my main view will not take effect.

This is my scaffold code:

```
    return Scaffold(
      drawerEdgeDragWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      body: ScaleTransition(
        scale: Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.98)
            .animate(_drawerAnimationController),
        child: Selector<GlobalProvider, bool>(
          selector: (context, globalProvider) => globalProvider.isDrawerOpen,
          builder: (context, isSidebarOpen, _) => PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: _pageList,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: _drawer(),
    );
```

This is the code for my list items that involve horizontal drag event:

```
    return Dismissible(
      background: DismissibleBackground(
        Icons.add,
        true,
      ),
      secondaryBackground: DismissibleBackground(
        Icons.add,
        false,
      ),
      dismissThresholds: _dismissThresholds,
      confirmDismiss: _onDismiss,
      child: body,
    );
```

I have tried to understand the mechanism of **HitTestBehavior**, but it has not had a substantial impact on me.

May I ask what method I can use to prevent the horizontal drag event of the Drawer from taking effect when there is a horizontal drag event consumption in the main view.I am very grateful.

Comment: any update on this? came to a similar issue where any scrollable child in a different class won't work if the parent `Scaffold` includes `drawerEdgeDragWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`

for instance, I'm trying to use in that child class a horizontal `SingleChildScrollView` but the draggables clash with each other leaving the `drawerEdgeDragWidth` dominant

Comment: update: this is a bug, the drag width takes both sides because apparently there's an enddrawer and it keeps receiving inputs for it even if it's empty or disabled-  which doesn't allow any activity for horizontal scroll in child widgets etc...opened an issue in the flutter repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/142234